# Error while generating an array of pointer

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures, struct, malloc

Trying to implement below code for some assignment but getting an error for malloc array generation "[Error] conflicting types for 'stack'" Any Help ??
Thanks in Advance.

```
#include<stdio.h>
   #include<stdlib.h>

    struct treenode
    {
        char info;
        struct treenode *firstchild;
        struct treenode *next;
        int flag;
    };

    typedef struct treenode *NODEPTR;
    NODEPTR *stack;
    // Trying to create array here
    stack=(NODEPTR*)malloc(sizeof(NODEPTR)*20);


    int main()
    {
        printf("YO\n");
        return 0;
    }
```

EDIT :

---

I can't move it to main , as i have to access the stack globally in different functions.
because Stack array gets destroyed when it go to another function. 
check here http://ideone.com/5wpZsp ,

---

When i give static declaration globally it works smoothly, here : http://ideone.com/3vx9fz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your initialization of stack to inside of the main method.

**EDIT** An example showing how the malloc data can persist to other function calls even though malloc is called inside of main.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct treenode
{
    char info;
    struct treenode *firstchild;
    struct treenode *next;
    int flag;
};

typedef struct treenode *NODEPTR;
NODEPTR *stack;

void test_stack() 
{
    printf("%p\n", stack);
    printf("%d\n", stack[19]->flag);
}
int main()
{
    // Trying to create array here
    stack=(NODEPTR*)malloc(sizeof(NODEPTR)*20);
    stack[19] = (NODEPTR*)malloc(sizeof(struct treenode));
    stack[19]->flag = 42;
    test_stack();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If i declare malloc inside main , it will be destroyed if i go to other fucntion , i need to access it globally.

Comment: @Manish - No it won't, the memory will be allocated until you free it. You can use "stack" in another function. Check my edit for proof.

Answer (score 2):

You can not call *assignment* operations at global scope. Try `malloc` operation in `main()` instead.

And the type of `stack` is not a pointer but pointer to pointer. Are you sure about it's declaration ?

Comment: Ok. You have to allocate 20 `treenode`'s in the memory locations you have to just allocated. And remember to free all of them.

Comment: I can't move it to main , as i have to access the stack globally in different functions.

Comment: Keep the declaration globally but do the assignment in the `main`. You should be able to access `stack` in all the functions after it's declaration.

Comment: It shouldn't work even with the static declaration. I think you are getting confused between the typedef and what operator `[], *` does on pointers. Pay close attention to the warnings on the link you posted. You will understand the mistakes you are doing.

Comment: I am able to give static declaration globally but not dynamiclly

Comment: I don't want to give away the answer. But I wrote a program {http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=11a0227e2b5259c88d417b107bf6a89f-7904cf83bb2b27db3f32fade22b567cc} to make you understand what mistake are you doing. Hope it helps !

Comment: You didn't get my question actually, I know what ptr to ptr does. My question was dynamically declaration of array of ptrs to the ptrs.
leave it . have peace & thanks for concern

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct treenode
    {
    char info;
    struct treenode *firstchild;
    struct treenode *next;
    int flag;
    };
    typedef struct treenode *NODEPTR;
    NODEPTR *stack;
   int main()
   {

    stack=malloc(sizeof(NODEPTR)*20);

    printf("YO\n");
    return 0;
  }
```

This will work.

allocate memory inside(`malloc)` your main.

There is no need to typecast out put of malloc. for further info see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc?rq=1) post

**EDIT :**

In your comment you mentioned that *memory will be destroyed when you move other function*.

This is not true. Once you allocate memory using malloc it will not be destroyed until you call free().

So if you want to access the malloc'ed variable in other function pass the variable as argument to other function.

See this example program below

```
    #include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
char *str;
void passMalloc(char **str);

int main()
{
    str = malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(str, "GoodMorning");
    printf("\nMain before pass : %s\n", str);
    passMalloc(&str);
    printf("Main after pass : %s\n\n", str);
    free(str);
    return 0;
}

void passMalloc(char **str)
{
    strcpy(*str, "GoodEvening");
    printf("Function Def : %s\n", *str);
}
```

Comment: If i declare malloc inside main , it will be destroyed if i go to other fucntion , i need to access it globally.

Comment: pass the memory allocated variable from main to where you want to use the variable. When you done free the variable else you will meet memory leak..

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Move the declaration of `stack` inside `main`.  There's no reason it should be declared globally:

```
int main( void )
{
  NODEPTR *stack;
  ...
```

Step 2: Move the `malloc` call inside `main` (you cannot perform an assignment or a function call outside of a function).

Step 3: Drop the cast; it's unnecessary<sup>1</sup> and just adds visual clutter.

Step 4: Use `sizeof *stack` as opposed to `sizeof (NODEPTR)` in the argument to `malloc`:

```
stack = malloc( sizeof *stack * 20 );
```

The result is the same, but this is easier to read, and avoids maintenance headaches if you ever change the type of `stack`.

Step 5: `free` your stack when you're done.  Yeah, for this program it doesn't matter, but it's a good habit to get into.

So after all this, your code should read:

```
int main( void )
{
  NODEPTR *stack;
  stack = malloc( sizeof *stack * 20 );
  ...
  free( stack );
  return 0;
}
```

Stylistic nit: Hiding pointer types behind typedefs is bad juju IME.  Pointer semantics are *important*, and if the programmer is ever expected to dereference an object of type `NODEPTR` (either explicitly, as `(*node).info`, or implicitly, as `node->info`), then it's usually best to declare that object *using pointer declaration syntax*, something like

```
typedef struct treenode Node;
Node *node;
Node **stack;
...
stack[i]->next = node->next;
```

etc. so the person using your types knows exactly how many levels of indirection are involved and can write their code accordingly (multiple indirection *is not hard*).  If the type is meant to be *truly* opaque and never directly dereferenced, but just passed around to an API that handles all that, then hiding the pointerness of that type is okay.  Otherwise, leave it exposed.

I tend not to typedef struct types for a similar reason, but I suspect I'm an outlier in that regard.

Ahd who broke the code formatter?!

---

<sup>1 - In C, that is; in C++, the cast *is* required, but if you're writing C++, you should be using `new` instead of `malloc` anyway.</sup>

Comment: If i declare malloc inside main , it will be destroyed if i go to other fucntion , i need to access it globally without passing it as argument.

Comment: Why can't you pass it as a argument?